Anypoint cli v4 - how to deploy an application and ensure it continues to use Object store v2?
I am working on a Mule 4 api that needs to use Object store v2 . This api is being deployed to Cloudhub 2.0 .
whenever the application is deployed / redeployed  the checkbox use objectStore v2 is getting  unchecked .
As a result when I am trying to retrieve data from object store , nothing comes up
Though via Runtime manager can , Obsejctore link shows that the data is present in object store
so in this case I manually check the use objectStore v2 which restarts the api and now data in object store is accessible
So to prevent losing state for this checkbox on deployment was looking at this link: ( we use Anypoint cli v4 to deploy app )
Tried passing these properties : ( --objectStoreV1 [false] and also  --property objectStoreV1:false )
However it did not work and post deployment the checkbox 'use objectStore v2' is again unchecked
any suggestions ?
anypoint-cli-v4 runtime-mgr:application:modify $EXISTING_APP_ID $COMMON_PARAMS --replicas 
$(REPLICAS) --artifactId $(ARTIFACT_ID) --assetVersion $(POM_VERSION) --groupId 
$(ANYPOINT_ORG) --replicas $(REPLICAS) --replicaSize $(REPLICA_SIZE) --runtimeVersion 
$(RUNTIME) --publicEndpoints $INTERNAL_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT --property 
mule.env:$CLOUDHUB_ENVIRONMENT --releaseChannel LTS 
--objectStoreV1 [false] --property objectStoreV1:false


The article that you are referring to is likely for an older version of Anypoint CLI. The correct flag is mentioned in the updated documentation for Anypoint CLI v4.




Flag
Description
Example




--[no-]objectStoreV2
Enables object store v2.Default: disabled
--no-objectStoreV2




If you want to use Object Store v2 you need to use --objectStoreV2. Also, I believe if you do not pass any flag it should persist the current state (apparently changes it back to v1) but this will make sure it is always deployed using object store v2 even if it was previously v1

thanks @harshank passing it as --releaseChannel LTS --objectStoreV2 worked ! without passing this flag the checkbox is unchecked , the data is present in object store and visually I can see it , but the code is unable to retrieve it , so the checkbox needs to be checked , thank you !
